# Select with inconsistent linkage

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table with three columns (ID, ReviewToId, ReviewFromId)

I would like to get record with the `ReviewToId` and `ReviewFromId` is not Consistent

For example, with pic attached:

I would like to return result with ID 4,6 and 8 Cos

1. 4 say it review from 2, but 2 review to 3
2. 5 review to 6, but 6 say it review from nothing
3. 7 review is 8, but 8 say it review from nothing

How to write the SQL query for this data result?

Using left outer join?

[image]

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @Jutiyi Showing your expected output would be helpful to anyone assisting you.  (It is mentioned in the previous link.)

Answer (score 1):

Next time please build an example like below.

```
create table dbo.Reviews
(
   Id int not null
  ,ReviewFromId int null
  ,ReviewToId int null
)
GO

insert into dbo.Reviews
(Id,ReviewFromId,ReviewToId)
values
 (1,null,2)
,(2,1,3)
,(3,2,null)
,(4,2,5)
,(5,4,6)
,(6,null,7)
,(7,6,8)
,(8,null,null)
GO
```

From start I can tell your problem is when two rows are reviewed from the same row (3 and 4)
so that row (2) can persist only one `ReviewToId`

Also you do needs two results, one for each column.

```
/* Wrong reviews from */
select r4.Id, r4.ReviewFromId, r2.Id, r2.ReviewToId
from dbo.Reviews r2
join dbo.Reviews r4 on r4.ReviewFromId = r2.Id
where r2.ReviewToId != r4.Id

/* Wrong reviews to */
select r5.Id,r5.ReviewToId,r6.Id,r6.ReviewFromId
from dbo.Reviews r5
join dbo.Reviews r6 on COALESCE(r5.ReviewToId,0) = r6.Id
where COALESCE(r6.ReviewFromId,0) != r5.Id
```

Results are:

```
Id          ReviewFromId Id          ReviewToId
----------- ------------ ----------- -----------
4           2            2           3



Id          ReviewToId  Id          ReviewFromId
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
5           6           6           NULL
7           8           8           NULL
```